# Receiving syntax error "Unexpected }" for a professional WordPress plugin, Sidebar Menu Widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm receiving an "Unexpected }" syntax error for a commercially available WordPress plugin, Sidebar Menu Widget, and I can't seem to find out why such an error is being thrown.  The widget consists of the following, with the "Unexpected }" syntax error happening at the closing brace of the function form($instance) within the class sidebar_menu_widget extends WP_Widget:

```
    <? ob_start();
    /*
    Plugin Name: Sidebar Menu Widget
    Plugin URI: http://webloungeinc.com
    Description: With this plugin you can display menu in sidebar according to nev menu.
    Author: Weblounge inc.
    Version: 1.0
    Author URI: http://webloungeinc.com
    */
    define( 'PLUGINS_PATH', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) );
    wp_register_style( 'style', PLUGINS_PATH . 'style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style ( 'style' );

    function _getSidebarMenu($menu_id='',$post)
    {
        $menuItems = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_id);

        foreach($menuItems as $menuItem)
        {

            if($menuItem->object_id == $post->ID && $menuItem->object == $post->post_type)
            {
                $parentMenuId = $menuItem->menu_item_parent;
                $currentMenuId = $menuItem->ID;
            }
        }
        $menuItems = (array) $menuItems;

        $_cnt = 0;
        foreach($menuItems as $_counter)
        {

            if($currentMenuId==$_counter->menu_item_parent)
            {
                $_cnt++;
            }
        }

        foreach($menuItems as $kmi=>$vmi)
        {

            $vmi = (array) $vmi;
            if($currentMenuId <> "")
            {
                if(in_array($currentMenuId,$vmi))
                {
                    if($currentMenuId == $vmi[ID])
                    {
                        if($_cnt <> 0)
                        {
                            echo $content = '<li class="m_title">' . $vmi[title] . '</li>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach($menuItems as $sis_menu)
                            {
                                // Parent
                                $sis_menu = (array) $sis_menu;

                                if($sis_menu[ID] == $parentMenuId)
                                {
                                        echo $content = '<li class="m_title">' . $sis_menu[title] . '</li>';
                                }

                                if($sis_menu[menu_item_parent] == $parentMenuId)
                                {
                                        $_other_cls = implode(" ",$sis_menu[classes]);

                                        if($sis_menu[ID] == $currentMenuId)
                                        {
                                            $_cur_class = 'current_m_item';
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            $_cur_class = "";
                                        }
                                        echo $content = '<li><a href="' . $sis_menu[url]. '" class="'.$_other_cls." ".$_cur_class.'" rel="'.$sis_menu[xfn].'" target="'.$sis_menu[target].'">&raquo;&nbsp;' . $sis_menu[title] . '</a></li>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $_other_cls = implode(" ",$vmi[classes]);
                        echo $content = '<li><a href="' . $vmi[url]. '" class="'.$_other_cls." ".$_cur_class.'" rel="'.$vmi[xfn].'" target="'.$vmi[target].'">&raquo;&nbsp;' . $vmi[title] . '</a></li>';
                    }   
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if($vmi[menu_item_parent]==0)
                {
                    $_other_cls = implode(" ",$vmi[classes]);
                    echo $content = '<li><a href="' . $vmi[url]. '" class="'.$_other_cls." ".$_cur_class.'" rel="'.$vmi[xfn].'" target="'.$vmi[target].'">&raquo;&nbsp;' . $vmi[title] . '</a></li>';
                }
            }

        }

    }


    /* Custom Product Specials Widget */
    class sidebar_menu_widget extends WP_Widget {
        function sidebar_menu_widget() {
            // widget actual processes
            parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = 'Sidebar Menu', array(
                'description' => 'Displays a Sidebar Menu'
            ));
        }
        function widget($args, $instance) {
            global $post;
            extract($args);

            echo $before_widget;

                $instance['title'] = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base);
                if ( !empty($instance['title']) )
                echo $before_title . $instance['title'] . $after_title;
                echo '<ul class="menu ' . $instance['class'] . '">';
                    _getSidebarMenu($instance['nav_menu'],$post);
                echo '</ul>';

            echo $after_widget;
        }
        function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
            return $new_instance;
        }
        function form($instance) {
            $title = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
            $class = isset( $instance['class'] ) ? $instance['class'] : '';
            $nav_menu = isset( $instance['nav_menu'] ) ? $instance['nav_menu'] : '';
            // Get menus
            $menus = get_terms( 'nav_menu', array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );
            // If no menus exists, direct the user to go and create some.
            if ( !$menus ) {
                echo '<p>'. sprintf( __('No menus have been created yet. <a href="%s">Create some</a>.'), admin_url('nav-menus.php') ) .'</p>';
                return;
            }
            ?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e('Title:') ?></label>
                <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('class'); ?>"><?php _e('Class:') ?></label>
                <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('class'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('class'); ?>" value="<?php echo $class; ?>" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('nav_menu'); ?>"><?php _e('Select Menu:'); ?></label>
                <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('nav_menu'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('nav_menu'); ?>">
            <?php
                foreach ( $menus as $menu ) {
                    $selected = $nav_menu == $menu->term_id ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                    echo '<option'. $selected .' value="'. $menu->term_id .'">'. $menu->name .'</option>';
                }
            ?>
                </select>
            </p>

            <?php
---->   }
    }
    add_action('widgets_init', 'register_sidebar_menu_widget');
    function register_sidebar_menu_widget() {
        register_widget('sidebar_menu_widget');
    }
```

I've indicated the spot of the error with an arrow.  After extensive debugging, the only thing that I can think of that could cause such an error is the insertion of HTML in the form() function.  However, I thought that ob_start() could allow such an interruption to take place while maintaining the flow of php via buffering the output?  Do I need to make some sort of ob_get_contents() call after the HTML to allow such a continuation?

I'm about to rewrite the plugin in order to avoid the interruption, but it bothers me that this is a commercially available plugin that won't work for me straight out of the box.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

I'm running PHP 5.5.12 by the way, and this error message is being given to me via XDebug.  Please let me know if you need any other information if you're looking to help.

Comment: I just looked at it in my editor and that bracket doesn't seem to be the issue. Also, should you be using the shorttags (`<?`) at the top of this plugin where you use `<?php` everywhere else within it?

Comment: Does the plugin throw the same error on a stock wordpress site running no plugins and a default theme?

Comment: Check if your server (PHP) has short_tags turned on or off. Its always best to use the long form i.e. `<?php` rather than `<?`

Comment: @Darren That was my thought as well, I changed the short tag to the full `<?php` but it made no difference, although I think you're just talking about general programming conventions.  I chose to leave it short tag in order to deviate as little as possible from the original plugin.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The short tag at the beginning is definitely not the issue, but I understand your point.  The first thing I noticed when I opened the plugin's php file was the short tag, I changed it to the full `<?php`, and it didn't make a difference.  Thank you for enforcing good programming practices though. :)

Comment: @ClarkZinzow What happens if you chuck error reporting on - `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`? And also what line does it say the "`Unexpected {`" is on?

Comment: @schoeffman I'll have to check, you might be on to something there.

Comment: WHOA.  It just started working.  And I don't know why.

Comment: I've been working on other parts of the site, mainly doing a dbsearchreplace on the database to update the domain name in the database and miscellaneous other things, and it suddenly works.  Strange.

Comment: Thank you all for the assistance!  If I had more rep, I'd +1 all of your comments for the help!